# How can I return a count for objects in my rails array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have SalesOpportunities that each have a pipeline_status. I'm looking to display a count of the opportunities with each pipeline_status in the view, and in order to make it the most efficient query I'm trying to add a method to the User class (User has_many SalesOpportunities) where I pull all the User's SalesOpportunities and count them. I use the following to get the hash:

```
self.sales_opportunities.unscope(:order).group(:pipeline_status).count
```

This returns a hash of pipeline_statuses with the number of opportunities that have this pipeline_status counted - like this:

```
{1=>1, 4=>1, 0=>1, 3=>2}
```

Now I need to pull this info out of the hash into instance variables that I can display in my view - I've tried adding a method on my User model, but it's not returning the info I need:

```
    def status()
    opp_count = self.sales_opportunities.unscope(:order).group(:pipeline_status).count
    opp_count.each do |key, value|
        if key == 0
            prospecting = value
        elsif key == 1
            qualifying = value
        elsif key == 2
            demonstrating = value
        elsif key == 3
            negotiating = value
        elsif key == 4
            closed_won = value
        elsif key == 5
            closed_lost = value
        elsif key == 6
            dormant = value
        end
    end         
end
```

This returns the hash above, but I can't pull out the values (e.g. qualifying ought to = 1 based on the hash output). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using instance variables, the way you have used - they are local variables.

Prefix `@` to those variables make them instance variables as shown below.

Also, note that `Hash#each` method returns the hash object as return value - the actions taken within the block will be visible outside only if they act on variables with higher scope such as variables defined outside the block, instance variables or class variables

```
def status()
    opp_count = self.sales_opportunities.unscope(:order).group(:pipeline_status).count
    opp_count.each do |key, value|
        if key == 0
            @prospecting = value
        elsif key == 1
            @qualifying = value
        elsif key == 2
            @demonstrating = value
        elsif key == 3
            @negotiating = value
        elsif key == 4
            @closed_won = value
        elsif key == 5
            @closed_lost = value
        elsif key == 6
            @dormant = value
        end
    end         
end
```

Comment: Thanks Wand Maker - I knew I was close to solving this, but had obviously gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, still can't seem to pull the items out of this array. Would it be better for me to add columns to the User model and just update them whenever a SalesOpportunity is added or updated? That way I can pull the info from the DB much more quickly on page load.

Comment: There is no array in your code, it seems like a hash.  Not sure whether you are expecting to return values or you are using instance variables somewhere else.  Adding DB columns to manage count is generally not a good idea as it can go out of sync due to multi-server/multi-thread environments in which code can get deployed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a hash. I may be over-thinking this (it works currently) but I figure as the count grows the amount of server hits from my current implementation (where I run @user.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 0).count for each status in the view) will grow too - eventually making the load time of the page a real drag.

Comment: Yes, in such cases DB columns for count make sense (Note: Rails Active Record has concept of counter_cache for this).  If you are adding your own columns, you will have to run some kind of batch which will keep validating the counts so that if they go out of sync - they can be corrected.   Also, if your DB supports materialized views - then, even that can be used for faster access to counts.   There are few other options as well - to use some kind of NoSQL databases that can be used for aggregate queries - I have seen people employing ElasticSearch to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know most of the terms you've mentioned, but I can certainly look them up tomorrow. I need to add a few batch processes to my app anyway before it hits production, so I guess this makes sense for the first once for me to learn about.